# Undefined variable: _REQUEST log entry appeared after PHP 5.4 upgrade

Tags: php, request

Loads of **Undefined variable: _REQUEST** error messages've been appeared in log after the PHP upgraded from 5.3 to 5.4 (debian wheezy amd64):

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _REQUEST in /mnt/exthome/kg/public_html/test/auth.php on line 1, referer: http://test/index.php
Mon Jan 20 09:55:58 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Stack trace:, referer: http://test/index.php
Mon Jan 20 09:55:58 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   1. {main}() /mnt/exthome/kg/public_html/test/index.php:0, referer: http://test/index.php
Mon Jan 20 09:55:58 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   2. __autoload() /mnt/exthome/kg/public_html/test/index.php:8, referer: http://test/index.php
Mon Jan 20 09:55:58 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   3. require_once() /mnt/exthome/kg/public_html/test/root.php:7, referer: http://test/index.php
Mon Jan 20 09:55:58 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP   4. require_once() /mnt/exthome/kg/public_html/test/user.php:4, referer: http://test/index.php
```

the request_order = "GP" in php.ini and the stack above don't use any $_REQUEST, but the required phps are loaded by __autoload function.

I guess the php.ini the apache uses was inherited from 5.3.

What'd I modify?

Comment: Give the code in which the error is happened.

Comment: <?


require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/settings.php");
require_once("root.php");

class auth extends root {

Comment: no. Where you set some values or use _REQUEST. I think here: /mnt/exthome/kg/public_html/test/auth.php on line 1

Comment: I couldn't use the code tag :( The line 1 is **empty**

Comment: There isn't any $_REQUEST in the files shown in stack list

Comment: $_REQUEST is a global variable, so is shouldn't be undefined :) It worked fine in PHP 5.3